# AVPlayer not playing HLS stream

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am trying to play HLS stream from apple sample live stream [URl](http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8).

I add ATS exception in `info.plist`.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>
```

When AVPlayer start preparing to play application crash. With below exception.

```
2016-09-19 16:15:32.562 AVPlayer[4630:268295] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
........
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the arrays that you're trying to load from your code you're trying to access an index that doesn't exists, the key "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" doesn't matter in your case.

Comment: Without 
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>

Xcode shows exception.

Comment: Ok but the fact that you need the http doesn't affect the error that you're getting, you're getting an error because of any of your arrays not because of the http connection.